# Param is missing or the value is empty: post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new on rails, I try to put post for my users, but I have an error for the edit option. The create, index, show and delete works but no the edit with the error :

> param is missing or the value is empty: post (on my post_params)

my _form.html.erb (with is for create and edit) :

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/post_error' %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @current_user.id %>

  <%= f.label :content, "Description :" %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :content, size: "60x12", placeholder: "Parlez un peu de vous" %><br>

  <%= f.submit "Créer l'annonce" %>
```

my posts controllers :

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :logged_in?, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
  @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page])
end

def show
  @post = find_post
end

def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "Annonce créée avec succès"
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def edit
  @post = Post.update(post_params)
end

def update
  @post = Post.update(post_params)
  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "Annonce modifiée avec succès"
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  Post.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "Annonce supprimée avec succès"
  redirect_to root_path
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:content, :user_id)
end

def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

I try a lot of things, but nothing work, the error change between the one and : `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you show stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the correct way

Look edited the controller in the right way

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in?
    before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    def index
        @posts = Post.all.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        if @post.save
          flash[:success] = "Annonce créée avec succès"
          redirect_to @post
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @post.save
          flash[:success] = "Annonce modifiée avec succès"
          redirect_to @post
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post.destroy
        flash[:success] = "Annonce supprimée avec succès"
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

    def post_params
       params.require(:post).permit(:content, :user_id)
    end

    def find_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

and the `@current_user` object I think it will be `current_user` like

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
```

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit action should not be use for update, it should be use to get the object which will be updated so change edit action

Also first make sure user is `logged_in?` before doing any action show `before_action :logged_in?` should come first than `before_action :find_post`

```
before_action :logged_in?
before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
def edit
  #@post = Post.update(post_params)
end

def update
  @post = Post.update(post_params)
  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "Annonce modifiée avec succès"
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Also make sure `user_id: @current_user.id` or `<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>`

which depends in which way you have defined `current_user` if authentication id done by `devise` gem then it should be `current_user`

Comment: @BenjaminRichard I hope , explanation given in answer will aware you for not to do future such kind of mistakes.